# Inserting a foreign key value & binding gridview at the same time

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I need some help on how to achieved Inserting a foreign key value in MS SQL at the same time binding the result in gridview in the same aspx page.

I have my code which is works fine and no error upon Build Solution but it shows the following line error in the browser.

> Line: 940 Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   A field or property with the name 'TypeName' was not found on the
>   selected data source.

I'm using MS SQL 2008 & MS Visual Studio 2013

Below is my code in my project

ASPX Gridview:

```
<!-- Main Gridview -->
   <asp:GridView ID="gvItemgrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ItemID"
         ShowHeader="false" CssClass="Grid">
                   <RowStyle Wrap="false" CssClass="row" />
                   <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                   <Columns>
                      <asp:TemplateField>
                          <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" ImageUrl="../images/Edit.jpg" runat="server" Width="12px" Height="12px" OnClick="imgbtn_Click" /></ItemTemplate>
                                  </asp:TemplateField>
                                         <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="50px" DataField="ItemID" HeaderText="ItemID" />
                                         <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="500px" DataField="ItemName" HeaderText="ItemName" />
                                          <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="500px" DataField="TypeName" HeaderText="TypeName" />
                     </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

C# Code:

```
   // C# Code
    #region BindTypeList (ddlType)
            // bind the Type list in drop down list..
            private void BindTypeList(DropDownList ddlType)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from inv_TypeList");
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                this.ddlType.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                this.ddlType.DataTextField = "TypeName";
                this.ddlType.DataValueField = "TypeID";
                this.ddlType.DataBind();
                con.Close();

            }

        #endregion

        //button save
            #region btnSave
            protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //Calling the database for Insert Statement
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

                // call stored procedure
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("inv_ItemList_Insert", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = con;

                // add values
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", txtItemName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters["@ItemName"].Value = txtItemName.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeID", ddlType.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters["@TypeID"].Value = ddlType.SelectedItem.Value;


                // add the result
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Result", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000));
                cmd.Parameters["@Result"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


                try
                {
                    // open the database..
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    // perform some actions here..
                    //btnSave.Enabled = false;
                    string result = cmd.Parameters["@Result"].Value.ToString();

                    // label notification..
                    lblMsg.Visible = false;
                    lblMsg.Text = result;



                    BindGrid();

                    // if meets condition to perform some actions..
                    if ((lblMsg.Text == ("Item Name: " + (txtItemName.Text + (" " + "already exists..")))))
                    {


                        // controls set to active..
                        txtItemName.Enabled = true;

                        ddlType.Enabled = true;
                        //txtRegister.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");

                        txtItemName.Focus();


                        // lblMsg notification display
                        lblMsg.Attributes.Add("style", "color: #FFFFFF");
                        lblMsg.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: OrangeRed");
                        lblMsg.Visible = false;

                        btnNew.Enabled = false;

                        // javascript messagebox "IP Address exist!"
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "msgExist", "msgExist();", true);


                    }
                    else
                    {


                        //Method in displaying data in reverse (last - first)
                        //Calling the database
                        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
                        string strConString = "select * from inv_ItemList order by ItemID DESC";

                        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(strConString);
                        gvItemgrid.DataSource = GetData(strConString);
                        gvItemgrid.DataBind();

                        //Highlighting the first row in gridview
                        object firstRowIndex = gvItemgrid.Rows[0];
                        gvItemgrid.Rows[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LemonChiffon;

                        //Display records
                        //current record per page
                        int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(gvItemgrid.Rows.Count.ToString());
                        int val2 = Convert.ToInt32(lblcurrentpage.Text.ToString());
                        int val3 = val1 * val2;
                        lblrecperpage.Text = Convert.ToString(val3);

                        //display page
                        lbltotalpage.Text = lblcurrentpage.Text;

                        //paging function disabled..
                        btnFirst.Enabled = false;
                        btnNext.Enabled = false;
                        btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
                        btnLast.Enabled = false;

                        //controls set to disabled
                        txtItemName.Enabled = false;
                        btnSave.Enabled = false;

                        ////current date and time
                        //txtRegister.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");

                        // lblMsg notification display
                        lblMsg.Attributes.Add("style", "color:#FFFFFF");
                        lblMsg.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:Green");


                        // javascript messagebox "Data successfully saved"
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "msgSave", "msgSave();", true);


                    }
                }
                //catching internal error
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    // throw some internal error in case there is   
                    string errorMessage = "Error in registring user";
                    errorMessage = (errorMessage + ex.Message);
                    throw new Exception(errorMessage);
                }
                finally
                {
                    //close the database..
                    con.Close();
                }
                // button new enabled..
                btnNew.Enabled = true;


            }
            #endregion

    // bind grid..
        #region BindGrid
        private void BindGrid()
        {
            // Call the Database & Stored Procedure for total Records
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("inv_ItemList_BindGrid", myConnection);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startRowIndex", currentPageNumber);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maximumRows", PAGE_SIZE);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@totalRows", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
            myCommand.Parameters["@totalRows"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@totalRec", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
            myCommand.Parameters["@totalRec"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ad.Fill(ds);
            gvItemgrid.DataSource = ds;
            gvItemgrid.DataBind();

            // Display the total records & pages..
            double totalRows = int.Parse(myCommand.Parameters["@totalRows"].Value.ToString());
            double totalRec = int.Parse(myCommand.Parameters["@totalRec"].Value.ToString());

            lbltotalrec.Text = CalculateTotalRow(totalRec).ToString();
            lbltotalpage.Text = CalculateTotalPages(totalRows).ToString();

            // current page value
            lblcurrentpage.Text = currentPageNumber.ToString();
            // conditional meets
            if ((currentPageNumber == 1))
            {
                // button first & prev disabled..
                btnFirst.Enabled = false;
                btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
                if ((Int32.Parse(lbltotalpage.Text.ToString()) > 0))
                {
                    btnNext.Enabled = true;
                    btnLast.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnNext.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                btnPrevious.Enabled = true;
                btnFirst.Enabled = true;

                if ((currentPageNumber == Int32.Parse(lbltotalpage.Text.ToString())))
                {
                    btnNext.Enabled = false;
                    btnLast.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnNext.Enabled = true;
                    btnLast.Enabled = true;
                }
            }

            //current record per page
            int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(gvItemgrid.Rows.Count.ToString());
            int val2 = Convert.ToInt32(lblcurrentpage.Text.ToString());
            int val3 = val1 * val2;

            lblrecperpage.Text = Convert.ToString(val3);


            // conditional meets equalize the last page value & records..
            if ((btnLast.Enabled == false))
            {
                lblrecperpage.Text = "";
                lblrecperpage.Text = totalRec.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                // point out the record at the end of the page..
                lblrecperpage.Text = Convert.ToString(val3);
            }
            // condition
            if ((lblrecperpage.Text == lbltotalrec.Text))
            {
                btnNext.Enabled = false;
                btnLast.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                btnNext.Enabled = true;
                btnLast.Enabled = true;
            }

        } 
        #endregion
```

SQL Stored Procedure: inv_ItemList_Insert

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[inv_ItemList_Insert]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ItemName VARCHAR(50),
@TypeID INT,
@Result VARCHAR (1000) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT ItemName FROM dbo.inv_ItemList WHERE ItemName = RTRIM(@ItemName))

BEGIN
SET @Result = 'Item Name: '+ LTRIM(RTRIM(@ItemName)) + ' ' + 'already exists..'
END

ELSE
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [inv_ItemList] ([ItemName], [TypeID])
VALUES (@ItemName, @TypeID);


SET @Result = 'Item Name: '+ LTRIM(RTRIM(@ItemName)) + ' ' + 'is successfully added..'
End

END
```

SQL Stored Procedure: inv_ItemList_BindGrid

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[inv_ItemList_BindGrid] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @startRowIndex int,
    @maximumRows int,
    @totalRows int OUTPUT,
    @totalRec int OUTPUT

    AS
    DECLARE @first_id int, @startRow int    

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SET @startRowIndex = ((@startRowIndex - 1) * @maximumRows) + 1

    IF @startRowIndex = 0
    SET @startRowIndex = 1
    SET ROWCOUNT @startRowIndex

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT @first_id = ItemID FROM inv_ItemList ORDER BY ItemID
    PRINT @first_id
    SET ROWCOUNT @maximumRows
    SELECT ItemID, ItemName, inv_TypeList.TypeName FROM inv_ItemList 
    inner join inv_TypeList on inv_ItemList.TypeID=inv_TypeList.TypeID
    WHERE
    ItemID >= @first_id
    ORDER BY ItemID
    SET ROWCOUNT 0

    -- GEt the total rows
    SELECT @totalRows = COUNT(ItemID) FROM inv_ItemList
    SELECT @totalRec = COUNT(*) FROM  inv_ItemList
END
```

Is there anything I missed in my code or any other way to achieved my requirements.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your SQL Storeprod has column 'TypeName' ?

Comment: Hi Marco, Actually it doesn't have the column "TypeName" but it is located in different table what I need is once the button save is clicked it will save in the ItemList table which consist of ItemName & TypeID the TypeID is the foreign key and it is primary key in TypeList Table. At the same time upon save I need to bind or view the data save in gridview but instead of TypeID I'm showing as a TypeName. Please check my code above. Thank you for your help!

Comment: yay, based on your error message "A field or property with the name 'TypeName' was not found on the selected data source."
you can't directly ==><asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="500px" DataField="TypeName" HeaderText="TypeName" />

use the "TypeName", you have to add some coding to retrieve TypeName by TypeID.

Comment: Is there anyway to implement it in my code? Revised and guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: In short, you can modify your storeprod 
"PROCEDURE [dbo].[inv_ItemList_BindGrid]"
declare another output name @TypeName, and Example: (select typename from yourtable where typeID=ID)

Comment: try manual execute your storeprod "PROCEDURE [dbo].[inv_ItemList_BindGrid]".
once you see "TypeName" column in the output, you will not get this error anymore.

Comment: Hi Marco, Thanks for your reply but I declare the following statement in my storedprod " SELECT ItemID, ItemName, inv_TypeList.TypeName FROM inv_ItemList 
    inner join inv_TypeList on inv_ItemList.TypeID=inv_TypeList.TypeID" where should I put the declaration for TypeName in my storedprocedure.. Thank you for your help!

Comment: it's better to show your "BindGrid()" function in c#

Comment: It's already there in the above code below in "C# Code" the BindGrid().

Comment: i suggest you look into " gvItemgrid.DataSource = ds;" in debug mode, check whether the "ds" has column "TypeName" or not.

Comment: Hi Mark, please see the above code in my aspx page I used the <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="500px" DataField="TypeName" HeaderText="TypeName" /> to display the TypeName column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I troubleshoot my code already and I found where the error occurs.

I revised the following SQL statement in my SAVE button

```
//Method in displaying data in reverse (last - first)
//Calling the database
SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
string strConString = "select * from inv_ItemList order by ItemID DESC";
```

with this one

```
string strConString = "SELECT ItemID, ItemName, inv_TypeList.TypeName FROM inv_ItemList inner join inv_TypeList on inv_ItemList.TypeID=inv_TypeList.TypeID order by ItemID DESC";
```

The error doesn't show up anymore, That's where it solved the error.
Thank you guys for your help!:)